# Different screen size and images in Processing

Tags: java, android, image

I'm currently developing my first game app for android OS using Processing.
I need to "cover" an ellipse (a circle) with an image, however I need to scale it in order to have a pic that fits perfectly defined circle proportionally with width and height (radius = width*(0.0375)). 
I have thought of making different versions of the same image-width, different size and choose one according to current screen resolution. 
My questions are:

Are there are standard screen resolutions for Android phones? If so, I can make one image per size and that's would be great? Can you tell me where I can find those resolutions?

There are more efficient ways to do processing?  I cannot use XML because I'm using Processing and all my images goes into asset folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard screen resolutions for Android are defined here:
http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html

Basically, they are 0.75, 1.0, 1.5, and 2.0.

And the easiest way to handle this is through XML. By Processing, do you mean http://processing.org/? If the framework does not handle this problem for you (and if it is OpenGL based, it really should), then perhaps it might actually be simpler to just use regular Android for development.